# How do I restore deleted kernel initrd files?

Tags: kernel

I managed to delete all of my initrd images in order to make space for new updates (I know - stupid)- is there a way to upload them back or do I have to reinstall my OS completely?
I don't have the live cd, but I could download it onto a usb drive I suppose. And when I start my computer I can only access the grub of course.

I am fairly new to linux so please keep that in mind.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, I'm going crazy without my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download the .deb package from the official repository server `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/`. Just use your web browser. There you have to find the kernel you need. In my case its called `linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic_3.2.0-35.55_amd64.deb`. So i made a folder in my home dir.

```
#mkdir linux-image
#cd linux-image
#wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic_3.2.0-35.55_amd64.deb
#dpkg -x linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic_3.2.0-35.55_amd64.deb .
```

Now you should see the files from this package extracted in the current directory.

```
#ls -l boot/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  792715 Dez  5  2012 abi-3.2.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140505 Dez  5  2012 config-3.2.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 2885822 Dez  5  2012 System.map-3.2.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4968400 Dez  5  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
```

There are your searched files, Now you just need to copy them into the /boot folder from your system.

The initrd needs to be generated. I would recommend to boot from a live system, chroot into your old system, and generate it by `update-initramfs -c -k <version>`.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me today. My volume was filled to capacity and I was forced to delete some files to make room but I deleted the initrd files from my old kernels (all of them) and now I am unable to boot to 13.10 and it gives me a Kernel panic error.

Can I just install a new kernel/intrd rather than fix the old kernels? I don't want to reinstall because that would erase my hard drive. If that's doable I prefer to just install a new kernel to go along with the upgrade of 13.10.

Thanks for your help!

-Fred